# distribute edge naturally

Tags: edges

in general, i want to distribute edges from image1 into something like image2 , so it looks more natural. Is there any automation tool for doing this ?

[image: source]
[image: target]

Answer (score 1):

You can rebuild the corner by bridging the edges.

1. Reposition corner edges and delete unwanted vertices
2. Select both edges and go *Edge > Bridge Edge Loops*
3. Adjust the parameters to fit your intended look.

[image]